# How to get a CompletableFuture from Jetty's HttpClient?

Tags: jetty, completable-future

Is it possible to use issue an asynchronous HTTP request using Jetty and get back a `CompletableFuture`?

I read [the docs](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.9.v20180320/http-client-api.html) but could not find any examples of doing so. I found [internal usage of CompletableFuture](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.9.v20180320/org/eclipse/jetty/util/Promise.Completable.html) but I couldn't figure out how to access it using the public API.

**UPDATE**: I need the `CompletableFuture` to return the response body as well (not just the response code and headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this with jetty client 9.4.x

```
var completable = new CompletableFuture<ContentResponse>();
client
  .newRequest(uri)
  .send(new CompletableFutureResponseListener(completable));
```

where

```
public class CompletableFutureResponseListener extends BufferingResponseListener {
  private final CompletableFuture<ContentResponse> completable;

  public CompletableFutureResponseListener(
      CompletableFuture<ContentResponse> completable) {
    this.completable = completable;
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete(Result result) {
    if (result.isFailed()) {
      completable.completeExceptionally(result.getFailure());
    } else {
      var response =
          new HttpContentResponse(
              result.getResponse(), 
              getContent(), 
              getMediaType(), 
              getEncoding());
      completable.complete(response);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to convert a `CompleteListener` into a `CompletableFuture` in this way:

```java
CompletableFuture<Result> completable = new Promise.Completable<>();
httpClient.newRequest(...).send(result -> {
    if (result.isFailed()) {
        completable.completeExceptionally(result.getFailure());
    } else {
        completable.complete(result);
    }
});
```

However, you are right that this may be done by `HttpClient` itself. Track [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2522).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think this option will return the response body. We're going to need to get a bit more sophisticated to get back a `ContentResponse` without blocking.

Comment: True, but you can add a `Response.ContentListener` when you setup the request to handle the content.